# firebase phone authentication failed ios

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17062 "{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription={"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.","errors":[{"message":"Requests from this ios client application <empty> are blocked.","domain":"global","reason":"forbidden"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_WEB_INTERNAL_ERROR}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add app transport security in info.plist, check below

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict> </dict>
```